# Git signed-off-by custom format

Tags: git

Is there any possibility to change default format of `Signed-off-by` line.

By default is:

```
Signed-off-by: user.name <user.email>
```

Some of project require another format, eg:

```
Signed-off-by: user.name <user.email> (github: account_name)
```

Comment: You should use [prepare-commit-msg hook](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html#_prepare_commit_msg) to update the message. You can find useful [git interpret-trailers](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-interpret-trailers.html) command to handle the trailer entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to max630's comment I prepared simple hook:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

NAME=`git config user.name`
EMAIL=`git config user.email`
GITHUB=`git config user.github`

if [ -z "$NAME" ]; then
    echo "empty git config user.name"
    exit 1
fi

if [ -z "$EMAIL" ]; then
    echo "empty git config user.email"
    exit 1
fi

if [ -z "$GITHUB" ]; then
    echo "empty git config user.github"
    exit 1
fi

git interpret-trailers --trailer \
    "Signed-off-by: $NAME <$EMAIL> (github: $GITHUB)" \
    --in-place "$1"
```

In order to use it, please put above code in  file: `.git/hook/prepare-commit-msg` in your project.

You also need add git configuration used by this script,  you can do it for project:

```
git config user.github "<user github login>"
```

or set globaly:

```
git config --global user.github "<user github login>"
```

Config items `user.name` and `user.email` most likely you have already.